# Is there a 'p4 have' equivalent in git?

Tags: git, perforce

To view the all files and revisions in a perforce workspace the command is simply:

```
p4 have ...
```

Is there an equivalent command in git?

Comment: Perforce allows syncing individual files to different change numbers, but in git, you always sync the entire repository, so there's no need to list revision information for every file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably looking for

```
git ls-files
```

This is not a complete analogue, since Perforce is so different from `git`, but it's my best guess.

You can also choose from a number of flags to specify which files to inlcude in the list:

```
--[cached|deleted|others|ignored|stage|unmerged|killed|modified]
```

See `git help ls-files` for full details.